# Access to class variable from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want assign to class variable, boolean result from asyncTask.

Something like this:

```
public class RandomClass{

    private boolean var1;
    private boolean var2;

    void abc{

        new AsyncTask{

            boolean var1;
            boolean var2;

            protected Void doInBackground{

                // here I am setting true or false

            }


            protected void onPostExecute{

                // I think I should set here, but it is imposible

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where is problem ? How to set true or false to var1/2 ?

Answer (score 0):

`RandomClass.this.var1` can be updated within the AsyncTask.

You don't need to copy/duplicate the variable definitions into the AsyncTask.

Also, `doInBackground` should maybe return the boolean values, and pass them into `onPostExecute`, but it isn't clear what you are actually trying to do

Comment: when I try to pass var1 into AsyncTask, I get "var1 cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Your question has no static methods/variables, so I don't understand your error. Please edit your question to show a [mcve] of the full code.